# How to restrict users to input only text but not numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, string, typedef

I'm making a program to input book detail using struct and function.

Here is my declare using struct to manage book detail:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char author[100];
    char publisher[100];
    char description[100];
    char ISBN[15];
    int quantity;
} book;
```

And the function to input:

```
void addBook(int* n, book list[1000]) {
    do {
        printf("Enter number of book you want to add: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        scanf("%d%c", n, &enter);
        if (n == 0) break;
        if (*n < 0 || *n > 1000 || enter != '\n') printf("Invalid input, please try again.\n");
    } while (*n < 0 || *n > 1000 || enter != '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Please enter all the information of book number %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Book title: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(list[i].name, 100, stdin);
        printf("Book author: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(list[i].author, 100, stdin);
        printf("Publisher: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(list[i].publisher, 100, stdin);
        printf("ISBN: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(list[i].ISBN, 15, stdin);
        printf("Quantity: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &list[i].quantity);
        printf("Description (optional): ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(list[i].description, 100, stdin);
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any method to restrict user to input only text for the following index:

```
printf("Book author: ");
fpurge(stdin);
fgets(list[i].author, 100, stdin);
```

If there are any numbers, inform the user to input again. I try to use do while structure for the loop but cannot think of the condition to check whether each character is number or not.

EDIT: thanks to @yLaguardia, now I know the answer. For everyone having the same question, use isdigit(variable) to check.

Comment: C Code cannot restrict what a user types.  Code instead needs to read all input and then handle that input as desired.

Comment: "*the condition to check whether each character is number or not*" => Does [`isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) suffice?

Comment: I'm thinking about using ASCII to compare if character is number after what user typed, I change my code to 

[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `do {
        printf("Book author: ");
        fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(list[i].author, 100, stdin);
        } while (list[i].author >= 48 && list[i].author <= 57);`
  
But it didn't work, can you point out my mistake ?

Comment: What if I change my name to "6"?  Am I no longer permitted to author books?

Comment: I'm just making a program based on what I was asked, and the only thing that is accepted is a book title with a number in it.

Comment: loop through your string trying `isdigit(string[i])`. If it returns true even once, ask the user again. If it never returns true, you're good to go.

Comment: @yLaguardia tks so much, it's the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `isdigit()` or `isalpha()` functions found in `ctype.h`, to check. You could also directly compare the ASCII values of the user's input yourself, using this table http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: isalpha() is the correct one. I fixed the response. Thanks